# Physical Stamp Machine Of Some Sort / Powered by Database/Software

Tags: c#

Apologies - I'm sure this isn't really the best place for this question, but since it's sort of technical and programmatic in nature...

Prints on paper - sort of like a time card punch - for putting document numbers on the 1st sheet of paper of a document.

Does anyone know of a device that could stamp paper but have alpha-numeric characters that are stamped be controlled by software ?

Specs:
Configurable "stamp"
Hooked up to computer
Each time stamp is used it would request from software the character sequence to be applied.

I'm thinking the device would be something like a typewriter - but in a configuration resembling something like a punch-time clock or numbering machine.   We need to be able to print characters in the following format "15-1-03495-S32"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it [asks for a product recommendation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: I disagree - it's no a product recommendation, it's... is there anything out there that meets this requirement that other developers have used.  Try googling for search terms.. "Electronic stamp" "digital stamp" "digital rubbert stamp" "programmable electronic stamp", etc. and see what you come up with.  I simply can't find anything like this, and am wondering if other developers have had a similar need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is equipment available that embosses material with alphanumeric symbols. Usually the material is rigid as it is carried through by a clamp and sheets of paper are unlikely to work.

Something like a Braille printer may be appropriate if it can be configured to use a symbology other than dots.

**Why not use a printer?** If the ink/toner is carefully selected, it may satisfy any necessary repudiation requirements.

A [daisy wheel printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daisy_wheel_printing) is almost what you are looking for, but to get em/debossed symbols, you need to have **two** synchronised wheels with positive and negative impressions.

Comment: It's for placing case #'s on court documents - case # format is changing and a real rubber stamp is no longer going to work.

Comment: There are inkjet stamps available that permit flexible configuration of the output that may meet your requirement. The stamps use widely available legacy cartridges and should support an extended application life-cycle.

Comment: Thank you - "Inkjet stamps" was the term that I needed - I was unaware that technology even existed! That should help to actually find a product that stays connected in real time (some products allow for sequential serial numbers and other things).  I found several products, inkjet pens and stamps that are very close in nature to what we need.  Appreciate the help.